# Server registered via RHSM to a Satellite Server can't load any of its assigned repositorys

Tags: redhat, yum, repository

One of my Redhat servers can't see any repositorys after registering with our Satellite server. I do have to say this Satellite server is newly setup and the newest Version -> Satellite Server 6 on RedHat 7.1. But so far all other servers could see all the repositorys after the registration.

cat /etc/redhat-release

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

subscription-manager status

```
+-------------------------------------------+
   System Status Details
+-------------------------------------------+
Overall Status: Current
```

subscription-manager version

```
server type: Red Hat Subscription Management
subscription management server: 1.5.0-30.el7sat-Katello
subscription management rules: 5.12
subscription-manager: 1.12.14-9.el6_6
python-rhsm: 1.12.5-2.el6
```

Messages from /var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log on the client-server:

```
Missing required tag 'rhel-6-server', skipping content: rhel-6-server-rh-common-rpms
Missing required tag 'rhel-6-server', skipping content: rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
Missing required tag 'rhel-6-server', skipping content: rhel-6-server-extras-rpms
Missing required tag 'rhel-6-server', skipping content: rhel-6-server-rpms
Missing required tag 'rhel-6-server', skipping content: rhel-6-server-supplementary-rpms
```

On Satellite Server it looks exactly like all the others that have registered. The only difference is, that this client is a VM on a KVM Host instead of an VM on a VMware Host. Google search didn't bring up anything helpful beyond that it is fixed on newer Versions, which i am already on. So i am hoping for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the Problem. It was a missing cert: `/etc/pki/product/69.pem` I copied that form one of the other servers and it instantly worked!

I got the solution from https://access.redhat.com/solutions/100423, but no reason why/how this would happen.

And i only got to that article, because in /usr/share/rhsm/subscription_manager/repolib.py the "tag" from the logfile is connected to cert checks ... *grumbl*